# univariate non linear optimisation in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find solution in R that performs similarly to MATLAB's trust region reflective algorithm. This question has been asked before but the author was asked to provide reproducible example. I couldn't comment there so the only solution was to post new question. Here's my example:

```
    x <- c(5000,5000,5000,5000,2500,2500,2500,2500,1250,1250,1250,1250,625,625, 625,625,312,312,312,312,156,156,156,156)
    y <- c(0.209065186,0.208338898,0.211886104,0.209638321,0.112064803,0.110535275,0.111748670,0.111208841,0.060416469,0.059098975,0.059274827,0.060859512,0.032178730,0.033190833,0.031621743,0.032345817,0.017983939,0.016632180,0.018468540,0.019513489,0.011490089,0.011076365,0.009282322,0.012309134)
```

Since initial parameter values are the central issue I tried using 'nls2' package which uses 'brute-force' algorithm to find good starting parameters. Even with that, nls and nls.lm cannot reach convergence. Here's some basic code for this:

```
    library('nls2'); library('minpack.lm')
    fo <- y ~ I(A * (x ^ B) + C)
    sA <- seq(-2,1,len=10) # range of parameter values
    sB <- seq(-1,1,len=10)
    sC <- seq(-1,1,len=10)
    st1 <- expand.grid(A=sA,B=sB,C=sC)
    mod1 <- nls2(fo,start=st1,algorithm="brute-force")
    fit_ <- nls(fo,start=coef(mod1)) # basic nls
    # or nls.lm
    fit_ <- nlsLM(fo, start=coef(mod1),algorithm = "LM")
```

MATLAB produced:

```
     a =   7.593e-05  (6.451e-05, 8.736e-05)
     b =      0.9289  (0.9116, 0.9462)
     c =    0.002553  (0.001333, 0.003772)

     Goodness of fit:
       SSE: 2.173e-05
       R-square: 0.9998
       Adjusted R-square: 0.9998
       RMSE: 0.001017
```

and yes, using these parameter values, R also produced the solution.
Question: how to obtain this in R without using matlab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at a the plotted data, I have no problem guessing suitable starting values:

```
plot(y ~ x)
```

The data is almost on a straight line through 0. So good starting value vor B and C should be 1 and 0, respectively. Then you only need to guestimate the slope of the straight line. Of course you could also use `lm(y ~ x)` to find starting values for A and C.

```
fo <- y ~ A * (x ^ B) + C
DF <- data.frame(x, y)

fit <- nls(fo, start = list(A = 0.001, B = 1, C = 0), data = DF)
summary(fit)
#Formula: y ~ A * (x^B) + C
#
#Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#A 7.593e-05  5.495e-06  13.820 5.17e-12 ***
#B 9.289e-01  8.317e-03 111.692  < 2e-16 ***
#C 2.552e-03  5.866e-04   4.351 0.000281 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.001017 on 21 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.084e-07

lines(seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 100),
      predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 100))),
      col = "blue")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I need to do this for many similar sets of x,y values; I can't post that much data to provide complete picture; I want to set one set of constraints and loop through all datasets. This case stopped the loop execution; therefore not a problem per se but slight difference from other cases caused R to 'abort', whereas MATLAB always produces a solution.
I encountered the same issue with fitting Gaussian mixtures (which is a whole different problem, I know), but the outcome is the same: MATLAB's trust region algorithm outperforms R in a wide range of situations and that frustrates me as an R user.

Comment: If you are happy with the trust region algorithm, use it. Package `trust` could be used.

Comment: In `trust` I have to specify the `objfun` which I cannot know in advance. The straightforwardness of matlab's function use is compelling.